# PANDAS - Count and store values with 2 variables columns

Tags: python, pandas

i am trying to solve a problem but i even know how to think. I have the output below:

```
1     JJAT  36.0
2     JJEL  28.5
3     JJEL  36.0
4     JJEL  36.0
5     JJAA  30.0
6     JJEL  36.0
7     JJEL  22.5
```

I need to count the respectives numbers, my desired output:

```
JJAT  36.0  1
JJEL  22.5  1
JJEL  28.5  1
JJEL  36.0  3
JJAA  30.0  1
```

the output can be in another format. I tryed groupby but it misses the correlation(name with numbers and counts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the liberty of naming columns as `name and val`

**Input DF**

```
    name    val
0   JJAT    36.0
1   JJEL    28.5
2   JJEL    36.0
3   JJEL    36.0
4   JJAA    30.0
5   JJEL    36.0
6   JJEL    22.5
```

**Code**

```
df.groupby(['name', 'val'], as_index=False).size()
```

**Output**

```
    name    val size
0   JJAA    30.0    1
1   JJAT    36.0    1
2   JJEL    22.5    1
3   JJEL    28.5    1
4   JJEL    36.0    3
```

**Input df creation**

```
d="""name,val
JJAT,36.0
JJEL,28.5
JJEL,36.0
JJEL,36.0
JJAA,30.0
JJEL,36.0
JJEL,22.5"""
df=pd.read_csv(StringIO(d))
df
```

Comment: perfect, thaks! I did not know about that .size()  :)

Answer (score 0):

Let us try [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html)

```
df.value_counts(['name','val'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this simple line code

```
df.groupby(['column1', 'column2'], as_index=False).size()
```